# Find and replace ruby except some phrases text file

Tags: json, ruby, replace, find, repeat

I'm pretty sure I got it wrong. But I want this program to run through the "phone_numbers.txt" and replace anything that is repetitive except `["Employee Marked Urgency as: low", "Employee Marked Urgency as: high"]` The result of this code is absolutely nothing. Nothing changed. Any tips?

```
file_names = ['phone_numbers.txt']
    file_names.each do |file_name|
      words_to_exclude = ["Employee Marked Urgency as: low", "Employee Marked Urgency as: high"]
      text = File.read(file_name)
      lines = text.split("\n")
      new_contents = lines.uniq.reject do |word|
        words_to_exclude.include? word
      end.join("\n")
      File.open(file_name, "w") { |file| file.puts new_contents }
    end
```

Comment: If you only need someone to review your code, you should ask your question on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you have any question like why your code does not what you want it to do, or you get errors when you run it, add that specific question with details.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood it properly, but using [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-uniq) with a block should do the trick:

```
require 'digest/sha1' # to generate uniqs

file_names = ['phone_numbers.txt']
words_to_exclude = ["Employee Marked Urgency as: low",
                    "Employee Marked Urgency as: high"]

file_names.each do |file_name|
  res = File.readlines(file_name).each_with_index.uniq do |s, idx|
    words_to_exclude.include?(s) ?
      Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(idx.to_s) : s
  end.join("\n")
  File.write(file_name, res)
end
```

What’s going on here: if we encountered the word from our list, we generate a uniq enough string to let is pass anyway; otherwise we use the original string to compare.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your code. I try to run it but it returns nothing but an error

Comment: ``block in <main>': undefined method `with_index' for #<Array:0x007ff0cf175760> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: I was unable to test this since I had no file on hand, but I believe you’ve got a good starting point.

Comment: Ah, sorry, typo. It should’ve been `each_with_index`.

Comment: Ah! ``block in <main>': undefined method `uniq!' for "#<Enumerator:0x007ff028184cf8>":String (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Don't worry I'll try to look it up.

Comment: `uniq!` (with bang) never appeared in my code. I have updated the answer, it should work now.

Comment: I tried to mess around and solve it but it was a futile effort